# Execute Anonymous Gradle Task

Tags: android, gradle

How can I execute anonymous Gradle task?

I want to add a hook on a certain task and execute another task with `variant.mergedFlavor.packageName`.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    tasks.getByName("prepare${variant.name}Dependencies").finalizedBy({
        doFirst {
           println variant.mergedFlavor.packageName
        }
    })
}
```

What I want to achieve is that `prepare${variant.name}Dependencies` task would be finalized by task 
`download${variant.name}RawData` task.

What would be the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as an anonymous task, but you can instead use a regular (named) task:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def downloadTask = task("download${variant.name}RawData") {
        doFirst {
            println variant.mergedFlavor.packageName
        }
    }
    tasks["prepare${variant.name}Dependencies"].finalizedBy(downloadTask)
}
```

That said, I'm not sure if the `prepare` tasks will be available at the time the `applicationVariants.all { ... }` callbacks kick in. If not, you might have to defer the `finalizedBy` line, e.g. by wrapping it with `project.afterEvaluate { ... }`.

Comment: How should I pass `variant.packageName` to that task?

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can also inline the variable `downloadTask` which makes look and feel like an anonymous inner class